# Mounting Drive to DosBox and using Debug.exe

Tags: assembly, emulator, mbr, dosbox

I am trying to track down the MBR on a scavenged Hard Drive. The hard drive won't boot so I've been trying to change the MBR through DEBUG.exe. The problem starts with my 64 bit machine because debug.exe is a 16-bit program that is no longer supported unless you have DosBox.

I understand that DosBox is an emulator and I have a basic knowledge of the division between User mode and Kernel mode as well as some fragmented research into the NT internal architecture.

My main question is; If I run DosBox and mount the hard drive I'm trying to debug. Am I viewing the memory on the hard drive if I run the Debug.exe from the mounted drive through DosBox or simple viewing the host 64 bit machine which is running DosBox?

I'm using this as a learning opportunity so any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: The reason I need to clarify this is because I am trying to use an assembly script in order to redirect the MBR to a new location. I do not want the program to corrupt the host machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A program called [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) will let you hex-edit sector 0 like good old sector editors back in the day under Windows.  Under Linux you have `bvi` which is like `vi` but in hex - simply open `/dev/sdb` or whatever the root drive device is (while it is unmounted) and hack away.

I don't believe DosBOX emulates low-level access to mounted drives - everything works on the file level -  so using `debug.exe` won't work.  Also, from what I recall, you have to load a sector into RAM using the `l` command or something similar, edit it in memory, and then write the sector back.

Keep in mind the utility [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) which I've used more than once to extract files from drives with overwritten partition tables.